# HTML Site title and Footer Copyrights

Tags: html, base64

I got 2 questions.

1) I was wondering if there is any kind of way, an code that I can add in footer for copyrights that will automatically pull Site Name and add into footer copyrights.

Since I bet my English isnt clear enough I will write a example.

If site title is "Example" is there any code that I can add in footer so if I write:
Copyrights 2012 - "it adds title here automatically". All rights reserved.

2) What is the best base64 encoder and can anyone pass me a link of how to use it as well.

I wanted to encode footer so I thought if theres a code to automatically add site title in footer, would be great.

Comment: yeh is it encode or crypt? I hope you know what I need :)

Comment: I'm asking because I really have no idea what base-64 has to do with a website footer.

Comment: And base-64-encoding your footer, with it's copyright notice, would preclude anyone from reading it without first decoding it. Unless you're trying to obfuscate your own copyright notice there's no point. And if you want to do *that* then don't publish that notice; it's *easier*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an element within your footer into which you want the site's title inserted, you can achieve that part quite simply with:

```
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
    footerElem = document.getElementById('footerElementID'),
    t = document.createTextNode(title);
footerElem.appendChild(t);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Qdebr/1/).

As for Base64-encoding your footer? I can't offer a way to do that, I'm afraid; nor can I understand why you'd *want* to.

---

**Edited** in response to comment left by OP (see below).

First off, put your JavaScript's `<script></script>` in the `<head></head>` of the document. And then paste this in:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
        footerElem = document.getElementById('footerElementID'),
        t = document.createTextNode(title);
    footerElem.appendChild(t);
};​
```

The only difference is that now it's wrapped inside of a `window.onload` event-handler, which means that it should fire when the `window` is fully loaded, and, assuming your HTML is accurately reproduced, it *should* work.

References:

- [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createTextNode).
- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById).
- [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName).
- [`node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.appendChild).
- [`node.firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/Node.firstChild).
- [`node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue).

Comment: I tried David... But I failed :( 

`<footer>
 <div class="copyrights"><h1>&copy 2012 <span id="footerElementID"></span>. All rights reserved.</h1>
  
        <script type="text/javascript">
  var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
  footerElem = document.getElementById('footerElementID'),
  t = document.createTextNode(title);
  footerElem.appendChild(t);​
 </script>
</footer>`

Comment: Oh well Ill figure something out from that. If it works on fiddle, it must work for me... Although it say:
Copyright 2012, - jsFiddle demo by davidThomas

Instead of Copyright 2012, - Edit this Fiddle - jsFiddle ? Since that is title of the page or not?

Comment: It's the title of the `iframe` in which the demo is rendered.